# Google Cloud Pub/Sup API: Almost 100% Errors on StreamingPull but still works?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have just started using Google Cloud Pub/Sub as part of an event-based architecture. I was somewhat surprised when I just checked the API dashboard and saw that I have almost 100% errors on the StreamingPull method. However, it seems like everything is working as intended.

I am using a listener within a `node.js` app (which is running on a server) and another one in a locally run `python` script (currently in development and doesn't run right now).

My `node.js` instantiation looks like this:

```
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

client = new PubSub({
    projectId: conf.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
        client_email: conf.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: conf.GOOGLE_CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
    },
});

const subscription = client.subscription(subscriptionName);

subscription.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
    console.log(JSON.parse(message.data));
    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.data).message;

    if (parsedMessage) {
      ... do things ...
    }
    message.ack()
});

const errorHandler = function (error) {
    console.error(`ERROR: ${error}`);
    throw error;
};

subscription.on("error", errorHandler);
```

Can anybody shed some light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and [explained in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull_has_a_100_error_rate_this_is_to_be_expected):

"StreamingPull streams are always terminated with a non-OK status. Note that, unlike in regular RPCs, the status here is simply an indication that the stream has been broken, not that requests are failing. Therefore, while the StreamingPull API may have a seemingly surprising 100% error rate, this is by design."